# LateInitializationError: Local 'prefs' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, riverpod, flutter-hooks

I am working with `riverpod` and `flutter_hooks`

I am trying to get implement `shared_prefrences` using this 2 approaches and this is what I get to so far  :

**pref_changenotifier.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

const _isloggedkey = 'logged';
const _boardingkey = "boarding";
const _apiTokenkey = 'apitoken';
const _rolekey = 'role';

class PrefChangeNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  late final SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;

  PrefChangeNotifier(this._sharedPreferences) {
    getPref();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool? _islogged;
  bool? _boarding;
  String? _apitoken;
  String? _role;

  String get apitoken => _apitoken!;
  String get role => _role!;
  bool get islogged => _islogged!;
  bool get boarding => _boarding!;

  void getPref() async {
    _islogged = _sharedPreferences.getBool(_isloggedkey);
    _apitoken = _sharedPreferences.getString(_apiTokenkey);
    _boarding = _sharedPreferences.getBool(_boardingkey);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setLoggedValue(bool logged) async {
    await _sharedPreferences.setBool(_isloggedkey, logged);
    _islogged = logged;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setTokenValue(String apitoken) async {
    await _sharedPreferences.setString(_apiTokenkey, apitoken);
    _apitoken = apitoken;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setBoardingValue(bool boarding) async {
    await _sharedPreferences.setBool(_boardingkey, boarding);
    _boarding = boarding;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setRoleValue(String role) async {
    await _sharedPreferences.setString(_rolekey, role);
    _role = role;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void clearAllValues() async {
    await _sharedPreferences.clear();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**pref_provider.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'pref_changenotifier.dart';

import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

final sharedPreferences = FutureProvider<SharedPreferences>(
    (ref) async => await SharedPreferences.getInstance());

final prefChangeNotifierProvider =
    ChangeNotifierProvider<PrefChangeNotifier>((ref) {
  final sharePreferencesData = ref.watch(sharedPreferences).asData;
  late final SharedPreferences prefs;

  if (sharePreferencesData != null) {
    prefs = sharePreferencesData.value;
  }

  return PrefChangeNotifier(prefs);
});
```

But whenever I call it using : `ref.read(prefChangeNotifierProvider).setBoardingValue(true);` , it throws this error

```
E/flutter (22947): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: An exception was thrown while building ChangeNotifierProvider<PrefChangeNotifier>#05878.
E/flutter (22947):
E/flutter (22947): Thrown exception:
E/flutter (22947): An exception was thrown while building _NotifierProvider<PrefChangeNotifier>#3bb8a.
E/flutter (22947):
E/flutter (22947): Thrown exception:
E/flutter (22947): LateInitializationError: Local 'prefs' has not been initialized.
E/flutter (22947):
E/flutter (22947): Stack trace:
```

i know that the problem is with my late initialization but what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes isn't that's obvious? You're using `late final SharedPreferences prefs`, then you use `prefs = sharePreferencesData.value`. You haven't initiated that variable, so you cannot do anything on it. You could change it to: `final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance()` in **async** function.

One more problem about your code, when you call *getBool(), getString()...*, it could be null (if you haven't saved anything on your shared preference). You could use something like this:

```
isLogin = prefs.getBool(SHARED_PREFS_KEY_LOGIN) ?? false;
```

Comment: the problem is that inside changenotifireprovider there is no async calls , so what should i do ?

Comment: ChangeNotifierProvider<PrefChangeNotifier>((ref) async {
    ...
}


add async after (ref)

Comment: iam telling you that you can't do that in the provider

Comment: have you got anything else in mind ?

Answer (score 0):

put this method in PrefChangeNotifier class

```
static Future initMySharedPreferences() async {
   _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}
```

and initialize in main.dart

```
void main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await PrefChangeNotifier.initMySharedPreferences();
   runApp(MyApp());
 }
```

Comment: it is also not working

Comment: also this is not the approach i was looking for , as my approach was working on a previous app of mine